# Solr highlighting breaks when qf and hl.fl are different

Tags: solr, solrj

I am searching a query say `"nurses"` on some copy fields `a_cpy,b_cpy,c_cpy` which are copies of field `a,b,c` respectively.

The values indexed in filed `a,b,c` are stemmed while values in `a_cpy,b_cpy,c_cpy` are not stemmed.

My `hl.fl` value is `a,b,c` while `qf` is `a_cpy,b_cpy,c_cpy and hl.q` is `"nurses"`.

The response from solr does not highlight `"nurses"` but highlights correct when search term is `"nurse"`.

Is this expected behavior or is there something wrong with my method?

Comment: If you're searching against the copyfields, why aren't you highlighting based on those fields as well? If you don't highlight against the same field as you expect hits in, the tokens (i.e. what will be highlighted) will differ from the ones actually generating a hit.

Comment: won't the terms searched in hl.q will be anlaysed accoording to analysers used in fileds in hl.fl? If this is the case then it should highlight correctly irrespective of what fields we search on. Also we cannot highlight on same searched fileds as they are not stored.

Comment: just an example: if i am searching for "organizational" on copy_fields and highlighting on original fields , it is not highlighting but if I am searching for "organization" (stemmed word) then it is correctly highlighting

Answer (score 1):

As you have already mentioned that one field is having stemming filter and other field is not having the stemming.

To answer your question this is the correct behavior and nothing is wrong with it.
We will see with below example why this happens bu using the solr analysis.

For the field named text, will use the below field type which does not have the stemming filter factory.

```
<field name="text" type="text_general"/>

<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

When you analyse the data for the above text field in solr analysis page, you will find that it does not match the data.

[image: SOlr analysis without stemming]
It does not match because the indexed data(tokens created at the end of filter factory) is different than the query value.

For the field named text_copy_stemmed, will use the below field type which is has stemming filter factory.
We have used `<filter class="solr.KStemFilterFactory"/>` while indexing.

```
<field name="text_copy_stemmed" type="text_general_stemmed"/>

<copyField source="text" dest="text_copy_stemmed" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<fieldType name="text_general_stemmed" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.KStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

When you analyse the data for the above text_copy_stemmed field in solr analysis page, you will find that it does match the data.

[image: Solr analysis with stemming]

The queried data is matched as it finds the token in solr. Verify the tokens created at the end of the filter factory and the one passed through the query.

I have indexed the below JSON and queried the same data with highlighting.

```
{
"id":"gb18030-example.xml",
"text":"jump jumping jumped organizational organizations",
"text_copy_stemmed":"jump jumping jumped organizational organizations"
}
```

[image: solr highlight with normal word]

[image: solr highlight with stemmed word]

[image: Solr highlight with non stemmed]

[image: Solr highlight with non stemmed word]

[image: Solr highlight with no response]

Comment: I am aware that there is difference in token generated for two different fields. What I wanted clarification on was that when I specify hl.q and hl.fl , will the terms in hl.q parameter be analysed according analysers used in hl.fl  fileds or analysers used in qf fields or just the raw terms (without any transformation) passed in hl.q  will be highlighted?

Comment: if you are using hl.q and specifying the field, analysis applied for the that field is applied/used and the tokens of the same fields are already created while indexing ...

Comment: so in the case when i am passing hl.q="organizational" and hl.fl= a b c (all fields are stemmed) it is not highlighting but when i pass hl.q="organization" and hl.fl=a b c  it is highlighting. why this difference ? is it that the analysis is based on qf fields rather than hl.fl?

Comment: The difference is because of the way you are indexing the fields...you are applying different field type to these fields..and the difference is because of the stemming...the stemming is created different tokens at the end ... at the end it matches those indexed tokens...if it exist it highlights...

Comment: @ak1234: Modified the answer with more information with different combinations

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. This is what is happening in my case also. The thing i can conclude from here is that hl.q values are not modified while highlighting. Exact terms in hl.q are only highlighted.

Comment: the value passed in hl.q is matched with the field mentioned in the hl.fl...and it will get highlighted if it gets match...and the matching is depend on the way the field is indexed...thats what I tried to show with the images....it has different hl.q with different hl.fl